# C++: String parameter in base class deconstructs when the derived class deconstruction

Tags: c++, string, inheritance, derived-class

I have a base class named A containing a string type parameter.

Class B is derived from A.

I define class C have parameter A* a, and 
assign it to B.

In the main function, I cannot get the string value of the base class as it became blank when b deconstructs.

I want it to output:

```
"Hello!"
"Hello!"
end
```

But the output is:

```
"Hello!"

end
```

Here is my code:

```
class A {
public:
    string str;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(string _str)  {
        str = _str;
    }
};

class C {
public:
    A *a;
public:
    void printOut() {
        B b("Hello!");
        a = &b;
        cout << a->str << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.printOut();
    cout << c.a->str << endl;
    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I deal with it?

Comment: *How can I deal with it?* --  This is not a clear requirement.  It is obvious what the problem is -- it isn't obvious what you really want to do.

Comment: You deal with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by not invoking it knowingly, and fixing it when it occurs as a result of a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, because `B b("Hello!");` goes out of scope, `c.a` is now a dangling pointer that will cause undefined behaviour upon being dereferenced. If you want it to outlive the scope you could allocate it on the heap instead :

```
class A {
public:
    string str;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(string _str)  {
        str = _str;
    }
};

class C {
public:
    A *a;
public:
    void printOut() {
        B* b = new B("Hello!");
        a = b;
        cout << a->str << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.printOut();
    cout << c.a->str << endl;
    cout << "end" << endl;
    delete c.a;
    return 0;
}
```

This gets messsy real fast though because you have to track the memory allocated yourself and call `delete` appropriately, consider redesigning or using smart pointers.

Comment: I've tried it and it outputs what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you storing an `A*` ?  You know that doesn't work, so stop doing it.

Make a copy of the `A` object, or a copy of the string it contains, and stop trying to do something silly.

```
class A {
public:
    string str;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(string _str)  {
        str = _str;
    }
};

class C {
public:
    string str;
public:
    void printOut() {
        B b("Hello!");
        str = b.str;
        cout << str << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.printOut();
    cout << c.str << endl;
    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I make a program that needs to store A * in class C. This program block is written for simply understanding what I want to do.

Comment: Well then you need to make it point to an object that lives long enough.